# Is the absolute Galois group the same as the automorphism group?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups, absolute-galois-group

Is the absolute Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}|\mathbf{Q})$ the same as the group $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbf{Q}}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}})$ the automorphism group in the category of $\mathbf{Q}$-algebras?

The first group is profinite and the second one seems to be an ordinary group.

**Edit:** The question generates a very interesting comments and discussion. At some point I don't understand why it was closed and why so many down votes. Anyway, Thank you for your clarifications and useful comments!

Comment: What is the definition of the Galois group, if it is not the automorphism group?

Comment: By definition, $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q})$ is the set of field automorphisms of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$. The latter is the same as the set of $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra automorphisms of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$. So, unless I am missing something, the answer is "yes" by definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "ordinary"?...

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko "Profinite" often carries connotations of being endowed with a topology (by taking an inverse limit of discrete spaces), as opposed to being "ordinary". In other words, I think Myshkin has correctly guessed that OP was thinking of the absolute Galois group as *defined* by taking an inverse limit of groups of finite Galois extensions.

Comment: The group $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$, when $A$ is a ring, is naturally a topological group (as a closed subgroup of the group of all permutations of $A$, itself endowed with the pointwise convergence topology). In the case $A$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$, this is indeed a compact group.

Comment: To build on YCor's comment, take the  group $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(\overline K)$; then it is profinite (as an abstract group) and the profinite  topology (basis of open subgroups given by the subgroups of finite index) coincides with the topology of pointwise convergence. For a reference, see eg. Bourbaki, Algèbre, chapter V, §10, no. 3.

Comment: @ACL $\mathrm{Aut}_K(\overline{K})$ can have finite index subgroups that are not open in the pointwise convergence topology. There's an example in Milne's Fields and Galois Theory notes (Aside 7.27).

Comment: @JulianRosen Thank you and sorry... In my above comment, after "finite index", add "of the form $\mathop{\rm Gal}(L/K)$, where $L$ is  a finite Galois extension of $K$"...

Comment: So the point in my comment is to say that the sentence "The first group is profinite and the second one seems to be an ordinary group." has little meaning. Both groups are naturally topological groups, and that the only difference is that the topology of the Galois group of algebraic extensions is widely known and systematically used, while the topology of the second group is quite well-known, but not as systematically.

Answer (score 7):

This has already been answered in the comments, but perhaps you can see it more clearly like this.

Take the isomorphism $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}|\mathbb{Q}) \cong \varprojlim(K|\mathbb{Q})$ as your definition of the absolute Galois group.

The usual proof of this proposition (Neukirch, Lang...) amounts to show that

$$\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}|\mathbb{Q})\to \mathrm{Aut}_\mathbb{Q}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$$

is both injective and surjective.

So $\mathrm{Aut}_\mathbb{Q}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ is by no means ordinary. Perhaps you were thinking about $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}^\times$, or something along those lines.

Comment: Suppose G is a profinite group. Do you know if its topology depends on how you view it as an inverse limit of finite groups? (ie, perhaps it can be viewed as an inverse limit of finite groups in two different ways. Will the resulting topologies be the same?)

Comment: @oxeimon, the topology on a profinite group comes from taking the inverse limit over *all* finite quotient groups, working modulo all open normal subgroups.  So there is no "choice" of a way to view the group as an inverse limit.

Comment: @KConrad Ahh of course you're right. Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that you answered my question partially  :) Thanks to YCor and ACL, I understand now the natural profinite structure on $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$.

Comment: @oxeimon, a remarkable theorem of Nikolov--Segal asserts that the topology on a *finitely generated* profinite group is uniquely determined by the abstract group structure.  This is false in the infinitely generated case.

Comment: @KConrad, I don't think I agree with your answer to oxeimon's question in comments.  For infinitely generated profinite groups $G$, one can make different choices of inverse systems of finite quotients, which can induce different profinite topologies on $G$.

Comment: @HJRW, reread my comment again: I am only talking about a given profinite group (e.g., I talk about open normal subgroups), not an abstract group without a topology in advance.

Comment: @KConrad: but there is little sense in your interpretation of oxeimon's question (which starts with "does its topology depend..."), because you suppose the topology is given (so you answer: if the topology is given, I can retrieve the topology; more precisely, you assume that the open normal subgroups are specified). HJRW's interpretation is that the underlying abstract group is known to be profinite. In this case the answer is no (one example being the group given as a vector space of continuum dimension over a field of prime order); it has plenty of distinct topologies making it profinite.

Comment: @YCor, oxeimon started with "Let G be a profinite group." I took that to mean G starts off as a profinite group and was just indicating that a suitable inverse limit construction recovers the group as a topological group. (There are multiple ways of defining profinite groups.) Admittedly this is not as interesting as theorems that recover the topology from the group structure.

Comment: @KConrad, I did of course read your comment carefully before commenting myself.  YCor has expressed my point of view precisely: your answer is a tautology, so it seems probable that the non-tautologous interpretation of the question is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

The automorphism group of $\overline{\mathbf Q}$ is equipped with a topology, induced by viewing it as a subset of the permutation group of an infinite set.  There is a basis of open neighborhoods in which the stabilizer of a finite subset of $\overline{\mathbf Q}$ is considered to be open.  This is the same as the profinite topology.

Comment: It's not just an analogy, if you view it (as I said in my comment) as a closed subgroup of the group of permutations of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$.